# SharePoint file name help

Tags: sharepoint-online, date, microsoft-flow, power-automate

I have a value `startOfMonth(addToTime(utcNow(), -1, 'Month'))` in Create File action in Microsoft flow. It gets the first date of the month and names the file as `2020-01-01T00_00_00.0000000Z.html`.

However, I want it to just give the date as `01/01/2020` which doesn't include the rest of the digits.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using `formatDateTime(startOfMonth(addToTime(utcNow(), -1, 'Month')),'dd/MM/yyyy')` and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh. It worked. Thank you. 
Can you answer this. So that I can mark this as answered?

Comment: Great. added as an answer below. please upvote and mark as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
formatDateTime(startOfMonth(addToTime(utcNow(), -1, 'Month')),'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: Done Ganesh. Just wondering If I can add months name for example January's report instead of this. Is it possible? I mean it gets the name of each month exactly as the same but in the output ( File name) will be like January Monthly report?

Comment: That will need some more calculations,. Check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Select-Day-or-Month-only-from-string/td-p/110875). it covers what you are seeking.

Comment: Ok cheers my friend.  Appreciate it.